# How i can order two foreach?

Tags: php

I'm doing something like a system notification. I want to sort the data in these two `foreach` by date but I don't know how. Please help me.

I have this code :

```
        $view_like_product=$this->db->query("SELECT lp.`product_id`, lp.`date`, lp.customer_id FROM `like_product` as lp, `supplier_products` as sp WHERE sp.`product_id` = lp.`product_id` AND sp.`supplier_id`=".$customer_id." ORDER BY lp.`date` desc")->result();

        $view_like_supplier=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT ls.`customer_id`,ls.`date` FROM `like_supplier` as ls, `supplier_products` as sp WHERE sp.`supplier_id`=".$customer_id." AND sp.`product_id` = ls.`product_id`")->result();

        $i=1;               
        foreach($view_like_product as $items){ 

                        //Limit
                        if($i==4) break;

        $product=$this->db->query("SELECT p.`product_name`,pi.`product_image` FROM `supplier_products` as p,`supplier_product_images` as pi WHERE pi.`product_id`=p.`product_id` AND p.`product_id` ='".$items->product_id."' GROUP BY pi.`product_id` ")->row();   
        $supplier=$this->db->query("SELECT c.`customer_id`,c.`first_name`,c.`last_name`,c.`company_name`,c.`company_pic` FROM `customers` as c, `like_supplier` as ls WHERE c.`customer_id`='".$items->customer_id."'")->row();
        ?>

        <div class="ui">
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>company_pic/<?php echo  $supplier->company_pic; ?>" height="40" width="40" /></td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><?php echo $supplier->company_name; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>has liked :</td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;">&nbsp;<?php echo $product->product_name; ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>supplier_products/<?php echo $product->product_image; ?>" height="40" width="40" /></td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><?php echo $items->date; ?></td></tr></table>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; } ?>

        <!-- Notif Like Supplier -->
        <?php   

        $i=1; 

        foreach($view_like_supplier as $items){ 

            //Limit
            if($i==4) break;

        $supplier=$this->db->query("SELECT `customer_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`company_name`,`company_pic` FROM `customers` WHERE `customer_id`=".$customer_id."")->row();
        $supplier_has=$this->db->query("SELECT c.`customer_id`,c.`first_name`,c.`last_name`,c.`company_name`,c.`company_pic` FROM `customers` as c, `like_supplier` as ls WHERE c.`customer_id`=".$items->customer_id."")->row();
        ?>
        <div class="ui">
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>company_pic/<?php echo  $supplier_has->company_pic; ?>" height="40" width="40" /></td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><?php echo $supplier_has->company_name; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>has liked :</td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;">&nbsp;<?php echo $supplier->company_name; ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>company_pic/<?php echo $supplier->company_pic; ?>" height="40" width="40" /></td>
            <td style="font:normal 12px Arial !important;"><?php echo $items->date; ?></td></tr></table>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; }?>
```

Comment: Looks like you ordered your first query by date but didn't specify the order in your second query. Is that where you are running into difficulties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done via `UNION` but it takes a bit of understanding of where you're going. I'll give a quick example:

Table X contains columns A (varchar), B (integer), and C (date).
Table Y contains columns M (varchar), N (float), and C (date).

You want to intermix the rows from the 2 tables, ordered by C.

```
SELECT 'X' as src, C, A, B, '' as M, 0.0 as N
FROM X
UNION
SELECT 'Y', '', 0, C, M, N
FROM Y
ORDER BY C
```

Now your resulting query will have the following columns:

- src - either X or Y, depending on which table it came from
- C - the date field everything is ordered by
- A
- B
- M
- N

The rows will be intermixed between the 2 tables and ordered by the C column.

Now when you process it you will do something like this:

```
while ($row = fetch()) {
    if ($row['src'] == 'X')
        echo "$row[C]: $row[A] $row[B]<br />\n";
    else // coming from Y table
        echo "$row[C]: $row[M] $row[N]<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok but i dont understand what is in the code view ("if ($row['src'] == 'X')") the X is the table or the column ?

Comment: i have do this

if ($items['lp'] == 'like_product')
     {
     echo 'OKKKK'; 
     }
     else{
      echo"NEINNN";
     }

but this don't work

Comment: I hope the answer above will be sufficient to get you on the right track. I recommend considering some PHP and mysql tutorials to get a better handle on programming in this environment as you flesh it out.

Comment: yes this answer is very good but in your code you say X in column and X in table, i can got the answer for your line :if ($row['src'] == 'X') plz

Comment: When I select from table X I put an "X" in the `src` column. When selecting from table Y I put a "Y" in the `src` column. Then when I am processing I can see whether to look at the X columns or the Y columns on the basis of looking at the `src` column.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2nd query by appending an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
$view_like_supplier=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT ls.customer_id,ls.date 
   FROM like_supplier as ls, supplier_products as sp 
    WHERE sp.supplier_id=".$customer_id." 
    AND sp.product_id = ls.product_id
    ORDER BY ls.date")->result();
```

Comment: yes but the items of like supplier are always bottom of like product, how i can fix this ?

Comment: Well, you loop through like product and then you loop through like supplier, so I would expect that like supplier would be at the end. We are using PHP in a typical procedural fashion and so the lines of code are processed from top to bottom. What was it you were expecting?

Comment: Yes i know, but i haven't the solution for sort the two foreach by date :(

Comment: Sorry - this is just not making sense. You don't sort a foreach. You sort rows of data. Are you saying you want the data in the 2 tables to be mixed together and sorted by data? You've GOT to give an example of what you're looking for!

Comment: Yes i want that : "Are you saying you want the data in the 2 tables to be mixed together and sorted by data?" and i need a solution for do that with my code plz

Comment: GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT YOU WANT!